# How do I calculate the division of a force from an angle along each axis?

Tags: trigonometry

I realize this might sound like a physics question from the title, but it's not real physics I'm dealing with, it's just a bit of trigonometry for a 2D game mechanic simulation.

I have a force (simply treated as a value of 100 in this equation) which I want to apply to the velocity of object A from a 40 degree angle. So to do that, I need to know how to divide the force along each axis.

How can I calculate that? This seems like it's probably basic trig. Looking back, I now regret ever asking my trig teacher "When am I ever gonna need this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described, the component of the force $F$ in the direction of the velocity is $F\cos 40$ and the component perpendicular to the velocity is $F\sin 40$